# How to make the text above the textformfield?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is the design I want to make

[image]

This is my current design

[image]

I'm new to flutter. My question is how to make the text above the textformfield. I have searched on the internet and tried to do it but still no success. I don't know where else to go to solve my problem. I hope overflow is willing to help me.

This is my code:

```
Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 100,
                                  child: Text('First Name'),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 200,
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                    controller: firstName,
                                    onSaved: (String? value) {
                                      firstName.text = value!;
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      hintText: 'First Name',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

200px is too big and structure I will prefer

```
Row
 -Expanded
   - Column (CrossAxisAlignment.startMainAxisSize.min,)
     - Text
     - TextFormField
  -Expanded
   - Column (CrossAxisAlignment.startMainAxisSize.min,)
     - Text
     - TextFormField
  -Expanded
   - Column (CrossAxisAlignment.startMainAxisSize.min,)
     - Text
     - TextFormField
```

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                filed(),
                filed(),
                filed(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded filed() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: Text('First Name'),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              onSaved: (String? value) {},
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'First Name',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is filed() ? Sorry I'm newbie.

Comment: I just created a method that will return single column, check last part `Expanded filed()`. You can name something else.

Comment: Thanks, dude. Your structure really helps me. Thank you so much. I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs because of wrong widget placement. Notice that you've Row inside a Column, but you don't really use Column's children in order to vertically place 'First Name' text widget.Also the row is basically redundant currently. You can make a Row of Columns I just shared below in order to achieve your desired UI. Try to play with it :)

```
child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    const SizedBox(
      height: 20,
      width: 100,
      child: Text('First Name'),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 150,
      child: TextFormField(
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          hintText: 'First Name',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: If I want to create a text and TextFormField for the last name like the design I want. Do I need to create a new column or can I still use my column?

Comment: And one more thing, do I need to make a new container?

Comment: I believe the best way for you to learn is to experiment with it yourself. Try both options you've just pointed out. Flutter dev tools should be very helpful, you can see clearly how every widget occupies the screen and conclude if it's necessary. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/overview

Answer (score 0):

To create the TextField you want, you just need to use a Column like this:

```
Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('First Name', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              onSaved: (String? value) {
                // firstName.text = value!;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'First Name',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

The result is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the input decoration of TextFormField, use `label` instead of `hintText`.

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    label: Text('First Name',
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

---

1. 

List item

---

You use the the property 'Labletext' of TextFormFiled or TextField....
to give the above text of the textformFiled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just use column widget first children is Text and second children as TextFormField.